# Awd dms permission issue while transferring data from cluster to cluster in sql

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, database-migration, aws-dms, dms

When applied got the error in status as running with errors, and in logs i am only able to find one error "Failed to get table definition for 'awsdms_control'. 'awsdms_apply_exceptions', checking if Metadata connection dropped by server". Followed by "Native error: command denied to user 'dms_user' for table 'awsdms_apply_exceptions ' ". Is it because of db permissions. If it is which permissions were required. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is because of permission issues, Admin permissions resolved it as temporary fix, for now and also we gave target schema in metadata.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).